# Walking through walls that I shouldn't be able to in python

Tags: python, runtime-error

I am making an RPG and I have a section in my code that prevents me from walking through walls. However I have a gate that can only be entered if I have a Key.

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self,item,x,y,picture,owner):
        self.item = item
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.picture = picture
        self.owner = owner
        Chart.chart.create_image(x,y,image=picture,anchor=NW)
    def grab(i,h):
        i.owner = h
    def discard(i,h):
         i.owner = None

class Move:
    def checkwallup(x):
        global up
        global down
        global left
        global right
        global xx
        global yy
        global marketwall
        global castlewall
        global bforest2
        global bmarket
        global bcastle
        global bforest1
        global forest1wall
        global forest2wall
        global cave
        global cave1doorR
        global cave1doorL
        global bcave1
        global cave1wall
        global key1
        global Key
        global hero
   #     global treetop
        yy = yy - 30
        pos = (xx,yy)
        if bmarket == True:
            if pos in marketwall:
                yy = yy + 30
                Chart.chart.itemconfigure(x,image=heroupstand)
            elif pos == (150,30):
                if Key.owner == hero:
                    Move.moveup(x)
                else:
                    Chart.chart.itemconfigure(x,image=heroupstand)

            elif pos == (150,0):
               if Key.owner == hero:
                    castle()
               else:
                    Chart.chart.itemconfigure(x,image=heroupstand)
            else:
                Move.moveup(x)
```

When I go to move through the gate nothing happens if I press twice, but if I press a third time I will go right through the gate as if I did not need to have the Key. Also when this happens everything else in my moving starts messing up.

Comment: Are you actually receiving some sort of error in your console?

Comment: Something that will help, you can do globals on one line like this:

Comment: global key, one, player, cheese, jihad

Comment: I think the problem is the line `yy = yy - 30`. Isn't that causing you to move up regardless of whether you have the key or not?

Comment: You should print debugging statements to figure out what your variables are at each step. `print (pos)`, once you set it, may point out where the problem is.